# Force VM to launch in 32-bit mode WebStart JNLP

Tags: macos, java-web-start, jnlp

I am running a Java 32-bit app on Mac OS X Leopard via Web Start. I need to make sure the VM loads in 32-bit mode. How can I do this in the JNLP?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer right after I posted. In the "resources" tag you can do a line like below. The "-d32" will force the 32-bit VM load:

```
<j2se version="1.5+" java-vm-args="-d32" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

Comment: As a note for **Windows** users. The **-d32** bit option is only working on a unix like OS. On Windows the JVM fails to start. It took me some time to find this out. Here is the reference of the JNLP File Syntax. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html