# Any solution to get the list of smartcards inside OS X?

Tags: java, macos, applet, smartcard

I am implementing an applet that gets some information from the user, including your name,
is system administrator, machine architecture and more the certificates and smartcards plugged list, all this is for checking the prerequisites of another applet.

In Windows all works perfectly, but I have problems getting smartcards info in MAC (OS X Lion Mountain), probably caused by this bug: [Bug DB:- JDK-7195480 : javax.smartcardio does not detect cards on Mac OS X](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7195480).

I found the following possible solutions (I think):

1. Use of another library without the bug as https://github.com/intarsys/smartcard-io
2. I looked at these discussions:

   - [Force the JVM to run in 32bit (-d32)](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23353736) as described in the discussions at apple forums.
   - [Force java applet to run in 32-bit instead of 64-bit JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7714102/418556)
   - [Force VM to launch in 32-bit mode WebStart JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1478139/418556)

For the first case I have the problem of lib be compiled to version 7, I need it to version 6,
I did not succeed to compile for 6, and the extra JARs are to big (+- 4MB).

For the second case, apparently this does not work on Windows (docs oracle javase 6 docs technotes guides javaws developersguide syntax)
And aparently have some limitations...

Does anyone know another lib (in Java 6) to get the smartcard information?
I need only reader name, card name and ATR.

Or someone would know a way to force the JVM from a Applet (simple method)?

Please, try  to be clarified because I am beginner in Java!

Comment: In this discussion speaking about this bug and possible solution via JNA... But I not believe to be necessary a complex solution for  something as simple! Obviously get a library without bug and working on java 6 would be ideal (the world is not ideal :-( ), but I settle managing to run the same applet forcing the JVM with-d32 ...

Comment: The lib in https://github.com/intarsys/smartcard-io  works fine in Windows and OS X java 7u60 (tested), but I is sought to work in java 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..Or someone would know a way to force the JVM from a Applet (simple method)?

We cannot really 'force' the user to do anything (not that we should), but by launching the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) we can *request* particular versions of the JRE.  Here's a rundown.

## Java Web Start - Runtime Versioning

Java Web Start can be used to ensure that an application
gains a certain minimum version of the JRE
(Java Runtime Environment) that it requires to run.
Web start can also be used to ensure a specific
micro-version of the JRE
is available to an application, or that an
earlier major release
is used (e.g. using 1.3, on a system where 1.6 is installed).

Unless the system is correctly configured, the user might be
prompted for download.

### Minimum Version

Java web start can be used to ensure a Java project is launched
with a particular minimum version of Java.  For example, if the application
uses generics, but nothing beyond what is available in Java 1.5, the
JNLP deployment descriptor might include a section that says..

```xml
..
<resources>
    <j2se version='1.5+'>
...
</resources>
```

### Micro Version

Besides being able to specify a minimum Java Major version, the
deployer can also mandate a particular micro-version.  An example
of where this can be handy, might be seen in changes to JRE's based
on new information about Daylight Savings Time (which can be changed
by regional governments at any time they see the need to change them).

```xml
..
<resources>
    <j2se version='1.5.0_11'>
...
</resources>
```

### Earlier Version

Web start has a handy feature in that it can allow us to
test applications against specific earlier Java versions.
For example, if the local build environment is based around 1.6,
but an application is supposedly 1.5+, it pays to test the
final product in a 1.5 JRE prior to deployment.  Invoking a 1.5
JRE in the 1.6 environment can be as simple as.

```xml
..
<resources>
    <j2se version='1.5'>
...
</resources>
```

Note the difference to the first example, which used '1.5+',
whereas this one uses '1.5' - to indicate that only a 1.5
JRE will do.

An alternative version..

```xml
..
<resources>
    <j2se version='1.5*'>
...
</resources>
```

### Prompt for Download

A problem commonly reported by people deploying applications
via web start, is that they are being prompted to download versions
of Java that are already locally installed.

Even if a specific Java
version is installed, it might not be flagged as being 'available'
for use by web start.
This can be easily fixed.

Open the **Java Control Panel**.

[image: <img src="jcp-javaapplication.gif">]

Select the **Java** tab and click the **View**
button of **Java Application Runtime Settings**.
You might see something like this.

[image: <img src="jcp-javaruntimesettings.gif">]

Note which ones are **Enabled** (right column).  This PC is
set up to use
`1.6.0`,
`1.5.0_11`, or
`1.5.0_08`.  Neither of the
`1.5.0-beta` or
`1.5.0_01` micro versions is available.
That is purely by my choice - if I needed to test against these
very early 1.5 versions, I could simply enable them as needed.

Ensure any versions of interest are **Enabled** and the problem
should be fixed.  Web start will be able to load that version of the
JRE and use it, without any prompt for download.

If you have versions installed that *do not
appear* in the **User** list, click **Find** to
launch the **JRE Finder** to
search for them.  The (Java 1.6) JRE Finder will
present a dialog with a message along these lines.

> In order to launch applications, Java Web Start needs to know
>   the locations of installed Java Runtime Environments.
>
> You can either select a known JRE, or select a directory in
>   the file system from which to search for JREs.

A [thread
on the web start forum](http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=38&threadID=5133244) also produced the following comments
from Andy Herrick.

> On Windows, the list of available JRE's is populated from
>   the registry which contains pointers to all the publicly
>   installed JRE's.
>   (It will not automatically include private JRE's, such as
>   those installed by a JDK install, where "install public JRE"
>   is not selected.).
>
> On unix it will only, by default, contain
>   the JRE it came with and any installed by java web start or
>   that came with any previous version of java web start that
>   had previously been run.

He adds a further note on specifying a download source..

> Using either:

```xml
<j2se version="1.5*" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se">
```

> or

```xml
<j2se version="1.5" >
```

> will get you any 1.5 version available on the system.
>
> If you use the href attribute, you are asking for the particular update release, so..

```xml
<j2se version="1.5" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se">
```

> ..will only work with `1.5.0_00`.

Comment: I'll test and see if it works for me! And I will present to my client and see if he approves...

Comment: I'am reading your post and from what I understand with JWS I can only determine the minimum requirements of the JVM, this is correct? what about java-vm-args = "-d32" which is spoken in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714102/force-java-applet-to-run-in-32-bit-instead-of-64 -bit-jre ? Although in this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html-d32  it is stated that this only works on unix platforms...